# if(function(s)) { statement } (Language C) (Standard return) (+newbie) (+abreviated expressions)

Tags: return

how are you?

```
int stack_empty(stack *s){
         return (s == NULL); /* I dont get this part, it returns what if its null? */
}

int main(){
         stack *s;
         if(stack_empty(s)){ /* what it means? like... whats the standard return of a function? */
               printf("its empty");
         }
         return 0;
}
```

My questions are in the comments of the code. Briefly they are:
-> Whats the standard return of a function?
-> What does return something == NULL means?

*I know what NULL, s or == means... my questions lies on those abreviated expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`==` is a test for equality.

If s is null then `s == null` is true the expression has a non zero value, so `stack_empty` will return non zero (probably 1). If s is not null, then `s == null` is false so the method will return 0.

The if statement is effectively saying `if expression is not 0`.

Comment: so normally 0 = failure, and 1 = sucess?; one more thing: int main has an return 0 which represents a success, so its kinda of confusing

Comment: Depends on context. False is 0, True is non zero. Success and Failure are different things than the "raw" true/false values. Often we use 0 as success and non 0 as failure (there is one value for success, but we can return many different values for failure depending on what went wrong).